# How to get width of an element with xpath Watir in pixels?

Tags: ruby, xpath, width, element, watir

I have trouble getting the width of a "tbody" element with xpath watir.
I have this code:

```
browser.element(:xpath , "//table[@onselectstart='return false']").tbody.tr(:index , 2).td.table.tbody.style "width"
```

this code returns me "auto", which is fine because the attribute must be set to "auto" so that it is positioned on the web automatically, but if I look with firebug it shows me the width of the element. As I can get this value in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
browser.element(:xpath , "//table[@onselectstart='return false']").tbody.tr(:index , 2).td.table.tbody.wd.size.width
```

For more information see documentation for [Element#wd](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#wd-instance_method), [Element#size](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Element#size-instance_method) and [Dimension#width](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Dimension#width-instance_method).

Comment: I ran the code and it works, but I have a discrepancy between what he says firebug and the result of the code. In firebug the width is 399px but the result of the code is 481px, which is the problem?

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you do not provide the link to the page, if it is public. If not, create a page that reproduces the problem and post the link here.